# (Qt C++) How to print chosen files/folders into a text file from a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, uitableview

I have a QTableView *tableView. When an user chooses the files / folders in tableView and right click -> choose "Print these items", I want my program to print those names into a text file or assign to a string. How can I do that? Thank you.

frmainwindow.h:

```
private slots:
    void showContextMenuRequested(QPoint pos);
```

frmainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "frmainwindow.h"
#include "ui_frmainwindow.h"

FrMainWindow::FrMainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::FrMainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    model1->setRootPath("c:\\");
    ui->tableView->setModel(model1);
    connect(ui->tableView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this,
            SLOT (showContextMenuRequested(QPoint)));
}

FrMainWindow::~FrMainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void FrMainWindow::showContextMenuRequested(QPoint pos)
{
    QMenu *contextMenu = new QMenu(this);
    contextMenu->addAction(new QAction("Print these items", this));
    contextMenu->popup(ui->tableView->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

Comment: Are you using `QFileSystemModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, connect your action to a processing slot:

```
QAction* action = new QAction("Print these items", this);
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered(), this, SLOT(printItems())));
```

Then you can access selected indexes `tableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes()` and using these indexes access data `model1->data(index)`:

```
void printItems()
{
    QFile file(QLatin1String("file.txt"));
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QModelIndexList indexes = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
    foreach (QModelIndex index, indexes)
    {
       file.write(model1->data(index).toString().toLatin1());
    }
}
```